# How do I make a SQL Command with INSERT AND COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert, count

I don't know how to COUNT a column named `id`. I tried

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `servers` (`user_id`, `ip`, `port`, `banner`, `disabled`, `vip`,`premium`, `name`, `status`, `votifier_key`, `votifier_port`, `country`)
             VALUES ('$session_user_id', '$ip', '$port', 's=.'id'.back', '$disabled', 0,'false', '$name', '1', '$votifier', '$votPort', '$country')");
```

But it's not working, because I couldn't get `id`. Can someone help?

Comment: **`1`** The `mysql_*` functions are **deprecated and will be removed in future releases of PHP**. Use `mysqli` or PDO instead. **`2`** Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Same fix.

Comment: Are you trying to count or insert? Counting would be something like: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table`. Please describe what you're trying to do in more detail.

Comment: Is your question about the part of the insert with `'s=.'id'.back'`? What is that supposed to do?

Comment: Im trying to COUNT and INSERT, like I wanna do SELECT COUNt('id') FROM servers as serverid,INSERT INTO `servers` (`user_id`, `ip`, `port`, `banner`, `disabled`, `vip`,`premium`, `name`, `status`, `votifier_key`, `votifier_port`, `country`)
             VALUES ('$session_user_id', '$ip', '$port', 's=.'serverid'.back', '$disabled', 0,'false', '$name', '1', '$votifier', '$votPort', '$country')");

Comment: Barmar, 'id' is a collum that I count..I want to count and discovery the value and input this value.

Comment: So you want to insert the total number of rows as a value in a new row? Just trying to clarify.

Comment: In that case, first count and then insert. But I'm pretty sure there is not a single scenario where this makes sense, so it's probably a bad design of whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: I will try to clarify.I want to COUNT and INSERT in the same SQL COmmand..Just that

Comment: Yes, I got that. And, as I said: do `select count(*)...`, get that number and just do an `insert`. No need to make it more complicated than that. If you really insist on a single query, try [`insert...select`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: Like that?: $numb;
 mysql_query("COUNT (*) FROM 'servers' AS .'$numb'.");  Than I put the variable $numb inside INSERT..Right?

Comment: Yes, but the query would be `select count(*) as numb from servers`.

Comment: Sorry, but It still not working ): Look: $numb;
 mysql_query("COUNT (*) AS .'$numb'. FROM 'servers'");
 $banners = "/dynamic_image.php?s=.'$numb'.&type=background"
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `servers`(`user_id`, `ip`, `port`, `banner`, `disabled`, `vip`,`premium`, `name`, `status`, `votifier_key`, `votifier_port`, `country`) VALUES ('$session_user_id', '$ip', '$port', '$banners', '$disabled', 0,'false', '$name', '1', '$votifier', '$votPort', '$country')");

Comment: `$numb; mysql_query(...)` makes no sense, but I can't teach you basics of PHP here. You'll have to read documentation on how to properly work with a database.

Comment: Are you attempting increment an ID of some kind? You can create a table with an auto increment key and simply pass null in for the value

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) request.

Suppose, we have an empty table test:

```
     test
|----+-------|
| id | value |
|----+-------|

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When we run this SQL request:

```
INSERT INTO test (value) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test`
```

we shall sequentially get `test` filling up with data:

```
| id | value |
|----+-------|
| 1  | 0     |
| 2  | 1     |
| 3  | 2     |
```

Use this approach for your table, and you'll get what you need.